# "People" was not to be preceded by a number, as in "Fewer than 30 people showed up"

Tags: uncountable-nouns, style-manuals, pluralia-tantum

From WordReference I discovered the following usage note

> At one time, some usage guides maintained that people could not be
> preceded by a number, as in *Fewer than 30 people showed up*.
>
> [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/people)

However, I cannot find any information regarding the reasons for this.

Comment: It may be that trad grammar demanded "persons" with a numerical determiner.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It could literally mean not using arabic numerals. Thus "thirty people."

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the etymology of “people”: it was not originally a plural noun form. It comes from Latin *populus* and French *peuple,* which are both singular in form, and generally singular in agreement (Latin sometimes has notional agreement, but I don’t know if that is attested with *populus*.)

The usage of the singular form *people* with plural agreement in English developed from a kind of “collective noun” usage, and since the singular form of a collective noun cannot be used as a countable plural form (we can say "the group are" or "the government are", but not "5 group are" or "5 government are"), it apparently used to be thought inappropriate to use *people* with a numeral. (Collective nouns may be pluralized to form plural count nouns like *groups* or *governments,* but that is irrelevant, as your question is about *30 people* not *30 peoples*).

However, present-day usage clearly does not restrict the use of *people* in this way. It can be used as the countable suppletive plural of *person* except for in certain special and uncommon senses, such as *grammatical persons.*

Comment: A collective noun such as "pride" in _a pride of lions_ is countable, as in _two different prides of lions share the territory_. Originally a singular noun (e.g. _The people **is** hungry..._–2 Samuel 17:29, KJV), the plural aspect of people is probably due to influence from Middle English _lede, leed_, a plural since Old English.